# Display view in Landscape orientation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am displaying a video and i need the view to rotate so it displays in a landscape orientation. I wrote the following code where it does exactly what i want. The problem is, when i click the back button, (the bar where the title of the carrier and time gets displayed) remains Landscape (for views that is suppose to be portrait). How do i correct this?

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now just put in your frames new location ie:

```
-(void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{
    if(self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
       self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight){
        video1.frame = CGRectMake(50, 650, 150, 30);
        video2.frame = CGRectMake(350, 650, 150, 30);
    } else {
        video1.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 150, 30);
        video2.frame = CGRectMake(610, 10, 150, 30);
    }
}
```

and leave this like how it was

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}
```

can call the orientation in the method you want it to change. So it knows..

example:

```
-(void)videoDisplayMothod {
    //video code
    toInterfaceOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

for the controller whose view is meant to be portrait? (the one you go back to after closing the video)